# Integrate Gebish into Gradle

Tags: testing, gradle, groovy, geb

I'm trying to integrate Gebish into Gradle.
I already found this nice tutorial: http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.9.2/build-integrations.html#gradle

The find is that I want to specify the browser with the commandline.
Now I have this code:

```
def gebVersion = '0.13.1'
def seleniumVersion = '2.51.0'

apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile "org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4")

    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"

    /*
    // Drivers
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    */
}

task firefoxTest(type: Test) {
    dependencies {
        testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    }
}

task chromeTest(type: Test) {
    dependencies {
        testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    }
}

test {
    systemProperties "geb.build.reportsDir": "$reportsDir/geb"
}
```

Also I have this big test that is located at src/test/groovy/test.groovy

```
import geb.Browser

Browser.drive {
    go "http://stackoverflow.com"
}
```

The problem is that if I run gradle with `gradlew firefoxTest` or `gradlew chromeTest` it happens nothing and I get the following message:

```
14:02:03: Executing external task 'chromeTest'...
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestGroovy
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:chromeTest

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.534 secs
14:02:05: External task execution finished 'chromeTest'.
```

How can I run my test through the commandline with the specific browser?
Also is it possible to build in Browserstack support?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have Gradle set up correctly. However, your big test needs to extend either `geb.spock.GebReportingSpec` or `geb.junit4.GebReportingTest` in order to be detected by the test runner as a test. It will then have to contain a test fitting the requirements for either the Spec or the Test. For example, see [GebishOrgSpec.groovy](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle/blob/master/src/test/groovy/GebishOrgSpec.groovy) and [GebishOrgTest.groovy](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle/blob/master/src/test/groovy/GebishOrgTest.groovy) in the Geb Gradle example project.

Comment: Thanks that works. Now when I try the chromeTest with the Chrome driver it's still starting firefox.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to running tests using multiple browsers, have a look at the [build file of the Geb's example project that uses gradle](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle/blob/master/build.gradle). Namely at how [Geb environment](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#environment-sensitivity) is set [here](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle/blob/master/build.gradle#L55) and then used in [`GebConfig.groovy`](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#the-config-script) over [here](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle/blob/master/src/test/resources/GebConfig.groovy#L20) and [here](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle/blob/master/src/test/resources/GebConfig.groovy#L26).